# Hibernate associations with an interface

Tags: java, hibernate, interface

I'm hoping someone can help me figure out a problem I am having with hibernate.

I am working on a billing system where different types of entities can be invoiced. The entities implement an "Invoicable" interface.

In my invoice class I have this line

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Invoiceable responsibleEntity;
```

The invoiceable interface looks like this

```
@MappedSuperclass
public interface Invoiceable
{
// Name to display as entity responsible
String getInvoiceOwnerName();

// Get email address to send invoice
String getInvoiceOwnerEmail();
}
```

I'm getting an exception when I run this

> org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on models.Invoice.responsibleEntity references an unknown entity: interfaces.Invoiceable

I've tried googling it and reading some similar posts but I can't get anything to work. Does hibernate support this type of mapping?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to use Inheritance in the Hibernate way to do this. Details can be found in the --> [Hibernate Inheritance Doc](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#d0e1168)

Additional information:
Hibernate is not able to wire types together where no database table is behind it. What does this mean for you. MappedSuperclasses do not have a table so there's nothing to wire together. So this is out of business. Most important keep in mind. When you request to read all parent objects. To which tables should he join? This is the reason why the inheritance system of hibernate comes in to play. You have to change the interface to a normal class. This should not be to much of a problem. Now choose an inheritance Strategy of your choice. Each of them have their pros and cons. Please read the doc to get an idea of which is best for your situation.

The following is an example of a the single table approach with an Invoice class.

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
    name="invoiceType",
    discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING
)
@DiscriminatorValue("Invoice")
public class Invoiceable  { ... }

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CustomInvoice")
public class CustomInvoice extends Invoiceable { ... }
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to summarise the key points here?  Stack Overflow doesn't generally welcome answers that aren't much more than a link to another resource.  Also, links sometimes break.

Comment: @mh-dev I did have a read through this doc but I can't see how to use an interface. It actually says there that interfaces are not supported with annotations. Since my entities don't stem from the same base class I don't see how I would be able to do this. I'll have to find another way.

Comment: I extended the answer, but keep in mind that the inheritance strategy has a performance impact. So please read the doc carefully.

Comment: Thanks, that's much better.  Your edit has earned my upvote.